# Почему не работает статика? Django

Tags: django

Подключаю в шаблон вот так: `{% load staticfiles %}`

Использую вот так: `<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

В settings.py: 
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)`

Иерархия: http://joxi.ru/8AnE5MGSqdG8b2

Как отображается на сайте: http://joxi.ru/12Mz78BT4NbLKA / http://joxi.ru/v293dE4sGMlLWr

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в: `<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Надо:
`<link href="{% static 'assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Ошибка все равно осталась, в консоли 404 not found

Comment: А ты добавил роут для статических файлов

Comment: from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

Comment: urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

Comment: http://joxi.ru/krDz138T07oLy2
Все равно.

Comment: https://github.com/maximifn/unvision вот код.

Comment: В коде на гитхабе ты же не внес изменения в способ подключения статических файлов как я указал в ответе

Comment: Забыл закоммитить, сейчас :)

Comment: Укажи в settings.py : STATIC_URL = '/static/' и при локальной разработке закоментируй STATIC_ROOT

Comment: Правильно подключай статические файлы в templates/base.html, как я указал в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @selimoves. Закоментировал STATIC_ROOT указала в STATIC_URL /static/. И в base.html все статичные файлы сделал в таком формате {% static 'url' %} и все заработало!